# React native authentication('Continue As')

Tags: javascript, react-redux, react-native, redux-persist

Good day guys,so i am trying to implement a feature in my react native app....After a user has logged in and later logs out of the app,i want to add a feature on the login screen to ask if the user wants to continue as the previous user that was logged in,please how do i go about it?
[Sample User interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI673.png)

Answer (score 0):

i'm new in react-native. but i think i have some solution:

1. Using local storage, store user id or somthing for login.
2. When user login, you can get device id and store it to your database. When user into app: check device id, detected previous user logged.

Answer (score 0):

When ever a new user logs in try to save details like email or username in Async storage(which is one way to store values in React native). And when the user logs out you can show the details which you had stored in Async storage.
Hope, this helps!